# Factorial of a number using events in C#

Tags: c#, events, factorial

I made a Windows Forms application that calculates the factorial of a number. All is fine, but now I have to do it using events. The concept of events is new to me and I've been trying to make it work for the past three days to no avail.

I have the form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    ... some function declarations...

    //public event EventHandler ProgressBarChanged;

    public int OnProgressBarChanged()
    {
        progressBar1.Value++;
        return progressBar1.Value;
    }

    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        initialize();
        label3.Visible = false;
        int wait_time = telltime();
        int number = reading();

        Facto mth;

        if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            mth = new Facto(label3, wait_time, progressBar1);
        }
        else if(checkBox1.Checked==false && checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            mth = new Facto(label3,wait_time);
        }
        else if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked == false)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
            mth = new Facto();
        }
        else
        {
            mth = new Facto();
        }

        mth.Subs += new Eventhandler(OnProgressBarChanged); // Error. I don't understand why

        int result = mth.Factorial(number);

        string display = result.ToString();

        label3.Visible = true;

        label3.Text = display;
    }
```

And the `Facto` class:

```
public class Facto
{
    public event EventHandler Subs;

    System.Windows.Forms.Label label_for_output;
    int wait_time;
    System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar bar;

    public Facto()
    {

    }

    public Facto(System.Windows.Forms.Label l, int time)
    {
        label_for_output = l;
        wait_time = time;
    }

    public int Factorial(int number_to_calculate)
    {
        int Result;

        if (Subs != null)
        {
            Subs(this, new EventArgs());
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(wait_time);
        if (number_to_calculate == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Result = (number_to_calculate * Factorial(number_to_calculate - 1));
            if (label_for_output != null)
            {
                label_for_output.Visible = true;
                label_for_output.Text = Result.ToString();
                label_for_output.Update();
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine(Result);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(wait_time);
            return Result;
        }
    }

}
```

The event should be triggered when the recursive function calls itself. When the event is triggered progressbar1.value from Form1 should be incremented with 1 (it should also decrement when it comes back from recursion, but I'm more interested in getting it to work first).

How can I fix this?

It's really confusing to me and I can only find examples which show messages or are very badly explained.

Comment: What kind of error/exception are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this error because your method signature are not equal:
.NET assumes that you have 
`public int OnProgressBarChanged()` as

```
public void OnProgressBarChanged(object o, EventArgs e);
```

This is a standart signature of all .net events. First parameter - is object, that raised the event. Second parameter is event data.
You can create your custom class, inherited from EventErgs to pass data to event handler

Comment: Also the return type should be "void", iirc.

Comment: @robertpas When you (in your `Facto` class) wrote: `public event EventHandler Subs;`, you chose to use the [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) delegate which is defined as returning `void` and taking two parameters, an `Object` and an `EventArgs`. You **could** also have said `public event Func<int> Subs;`. Then the return type would be `int`, and there would be zero parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task I would suggest using a BackgroundWorker with a ProgressChanged event handler, so that the calculations and UI updates are carried out on separate threads. See the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for a similar example with Fibonacci number calculation and a progress bar.